# Loop isn't iterating over last line of list

Tags: loops, ansible

I have created a template within a playbook which I want to iterate through with a list of hashes. The output of this I want to add to another var to use in a following module.

The template works and the loop looks like it works, but it never adds the last item in the list. I have recreated it in a test play.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Init
    set_fact:
      foo: []
      fqdn: "test.com"
      template: []

  - name: portlist
    set_fact:
      portlist:
      - { port: 9091, index: 1 }
      - { port: 9092, index: 2 }
      - { port: 9093, index: 3 }
      - { port: 9094, index: 4 }

  - name: generate policy
    set_fact:
      template:
      - name: "traffic to {{ item.port }}"
        index: "{{ item.index }}"
        match:
          desc: "[{{ item.port }}]" # The field needs to be passed as a list
          name: "{{ fqdn }}_{{ item.port }}"
          port: "{{ item.port }}"
      foo: "{{ foo + template }}"
    loop: "{{ portlist }}"

  - debug:
      var: foo
```

I understand I can make this play smaller with defaults rather than initializing vars but this felt easier to read for troubleshooting.

The play results in a list of hashes which then I can input into a policy module. However it only ever gives me 3 items in the list and misses off the last item in the portlist.

```
TASK [debug] ***************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "foo": [
        {
            "action": {
                "ref": "test.com_9091",
                "this": true
            },
            "enable": true,
            "index": "1",
            "match": {
                "port": {
                    "criteria": "IS_IN",
                    "port": [
                        9091
                    ]
                }
            },
            "name": "traffic to 9091"
        },
        {
            "action": {
                "ref": "test.com_9092",
                "this": true
            },
            "enable": true,
            "index": "2",
            "match": {
                "port": {
                    "criteria": "IS_IN",
                    "port": [
                        9092
                    ]
                }
            },
            "name": "traffic to 9092"
        },
        {
            "action": {
                "ref": "test.com_9093",
                "this": true
            },
            "enable": true,
            "index": "3",
            "match": {
                "port": {
                    "criteria": "IS_IN",
                    "port": [
                        9093
                    ]
                }
            },
            "name": "traffic to 9093"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the fact that variables defined via `set_fact` aren't available until after the `set_fact` task has finished. This means that when you set:

```
foo: "{{ foo + template }}"
```

You see the value of `template` from the previous loop iteration.

One way of dealing with this is to rewrite your `set_fact` task to set `foo` directly:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    fqdn: "test.com"
    portlist:
      - {port: 9091, index: 1}
      - {port: 9092, index: 2}
      - {port: 9093, index: 3}
      - {port: 9094, index: 4}
  tasks:
    - name: generate policy
      set_fact:
        foo: >-
          {{
            foo + [{
              'name': 'traffic to {}'.format(item.port),
              'index': item.index,
              'match': {
                'desc': "[{}]".format(item.port),
                'name': '{}_{}'.format(fqdn, item.port),
                'port': item.port
              }
            }]
          }}
      vars:
        foo: []
      loop: "{{ portlist }}"

    - debug:
        var: foo
```

This will output:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "foo": [
        {
            "index": 1,
            "match": {
                "desc": "[9091]",
                "name": "test.com_9091",
                "port": 9091
            },
            "name": "traffic to 9091"
        },
        {
            "index": 2,
            "match": {
                "desc": "[9092]",
                "name": "test.com_9092",
                "port": 9092
            },
            "name": "traffic to 9092"
        },
        {
            "index": 3,
            "match": {
                "desc": "[9093]",
                "name": "test.com_9093",
                "port": 9093
            },
            "name": "traffic to 9093"
        },
        {
            "index": 4,
            "match": {
                "desc": "[9094]",
                "name": "test.com_9094",
                "port": 9094
            },
            "name": "traffic to 9094"
        }
    ]
}
```

If you find your template-based solution more readable, you could rewrite it using two `set_fact` tasks like this:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    fqdn: "test.com"
    portlist:
      - {port: 9091, index: 1}
      - {port: 9092, index: 2}
      - {port: 9093, index: 3}
      - {port: 9094, index: 4}
  tasks:
  - name: generate policy
    set_fact:
      template:
        name: "traffic to {{ item.port }}"
        index: "{{ item.index }}"
        match:
          desc: "[{{ item.port }}]" # The field needs to be passed as a list
          name: "{{ fqdn }}_{{ item.port }}"
          port: "{{ item.port }}"
    loop: "{{ portlist }}"
    register: foo

  - set_fact:
      foo: "{{ foo.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.template') | list }}"

  - debug:
      var: foo
```

Comment: I much prefer the initial answer, I've transposed it to my environment and one thing is still stopping me. `'desc': "[{}]".format(item.port)` is giving me a `"internal literal for int() with base10"' error. But in my test it works fine! Great answer

Comment: I figured it out, it had to pass that object as a list but the template was passing as a string "[9091]". changed to using `port: [item.port]` as I would only ever have one port in that field.